# Hosting a web application in Azure that consumes on premise web services and ActiveMQ

Tags: azure

I'm looking at ways to host our web site in Azure. The Web application consumes on-premise web services and send/receive messages from ActiveMQ hosted on-premise. Is this possible? Any pointers will be helpful.

Comment: Not sure why someone flagged to close this as "opinion based"... They question is asking if it's possible, so no opinion necessary. This is a good question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short Answer: Yes, it's possible. Mixing Azure and On-Prem resources is what's called the Hybrid Cloud.

Long Answer:
You can use Azure App Service Environment to setup a Virtual Network with an Azure Web App that will allow for a VPN connection to be setup between your on-premises network and the Azure VNet. If VPN setup isn't an option of you, then you could use the Azure Service Bus Relay service to connect an on-premises WCF Web Service to the Azure Web App. Additionally, a Biztalk Hybrid Connection could be used to tunnel through the firewall between your on-premises resources and the Azure Web App. Hybrid Cloud is fully supported in Microsoft Azure and there are a few options to choose depending on which fits your needs / scenario best.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a VPN on Azure, add the web site to it and then create a site to point VPN connection to add the VM that has the on-premise web service to it.

Another solution, if your web service is developed in WCF, you can use Service Bus Relay with your web service, this will make it accessible from your Azure web site.